# Where can I obtain the SQLpackage command-line utility?

Tags: command-line, sql

I am trying to use the SQL Package command-line utility (sqlpackage.exe) on a SQL Server, but I cannot find it anywhere online.

Is it something that I can download as a standalone utility, or is it part of some greater software bundle that I have to install?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Standalone downloads are available from [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download).

It's also included in the "SQL Server Data Tools" from Microsoft.

> SQL Server Data Tools proves command-line tools that enable a number of project-oriented database development scenarios.

More info from MS [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531248(v=vs.103).aspx).

You can download the "SQL Server Data Tools" from MS [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027).

Comment: Is there a version which doesnt come with visual studio ?

Comment: @SaintGerbil I'm not sure what you mean? The downloads on the linked page do not include Visual Studio.

Comment: On installing "SSDTSetup.exe" you get an error towards the end "this application requires Microsoft Visual Studio. Install Microsoft Visual Studio and run the installer again." where I want to install it on a server which has a SQL 2008 R2 and no VS so I want to be able to run the tools (like sqlpackage.exe) without all the designer files.

Comment: @SaintGerbil  You want the "Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework" (aka "DACFx")  At the moment, the [May 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46898) version is the latest.

(MS does a terrible job with organizing their downloads - It's almost impossible to confirm what the latest version of anything is...)

Comment: I find it frustrating that I have to come to SO to found where to download this.  The download page isn't even on the first result page of Google when you search "sqlpackage.exe download".  And Microsoft's own page on sqlpackage doesn't have a download link anywhere.

Answer (score 19):

The following StackOverflow answer gives full details of the various ways you can obtain the latest version of SqlPackage, which works with SQL Server 2005-2014, and where to find it once it's installed:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23376593/216440

To quote:

> Yes, there is a new version supporting SQL Server 2005-2014 available
>   and it installs into a different location than the previous (SQL
>   Server 2012 and lower) version. In fact, you'll have different install
>   locations depending on if you just use SSDT or if you install it as
>   part of SSMS or the standalone installer.
>
> - SSDT installs the Dac DLLs inside Visual Studio in the latest releases. This is to avoid side by side issues (Visual Studio 2012 vs
>     2013 vs SSMS) that required all to be updated to use the latest code.
>
>   - If you have [updated to the latest SSDT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027), you'll find SqlPackage.exe and the related DLLs in the **VS Install  Directory\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120**. For VS2013
>       the VS install directory is **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>       Studio 12.0**.
> - [SSMS for SQL Server 2014](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434042.aspx) and the standalone [Dac Framework MSI](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42293) both install to the system-wide location. This is **C:\Program
>     Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Dac\bin**.

Comment: Your  "Dac Framework MSI" link is to the April 2014 version.  At the moment, the [May 2015 version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46898) in @Simon Wang's answer is the latest.

Answer (score 8):

Be warned, this utility is SQL server version specific.

When (if) this is installed it will be found in the 'DAC\bin' subfolder of your SQL server install.  So for SQL Server 2012 this will be in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin
```

SQL Server 2012 has internal version 11.0 and SQL Server 2014 has internal version 12.0.  So for SQL Server 2014 you find SqlPackage here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just realized the tool has a standalone version installer which is called SQL Server® Data-Tier Application Framework, it requires Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types, and Microsoft SQL Server Transact-SQL ScriptDom.

For latest download link(Version 2014): [Microsoft® SQL Server® Data-Tier Application Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46898)

Other two required components can be download as part of [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295)

After installation the SqlPackage can be found C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin if you are installing x86 version.

This is a way much better and easier way to manage a deploy from server.

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to be the smallest "stand alone" installer I could find for the tool in question.

Microsoft® SQL Server® Data-Tier Application Framework (June 30 2016)

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=53013

this installed it here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe

Answer (score 1):

If you have Visual Studio with SSDT installed, try

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\**130**\sqlpackage.exe

or

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\**120**\sqlpackage.exe